# Lighting Component Communication through Event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Can we communicate between Sibling Component using Event in Lighting Component?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please could you read the [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/288482/edit) your question to add detail as to what you have tried and where you are stuck. Please also note that you have put both Aura and LWC as tags, which is confusing. Which framework are you actually developing with? (This should be clear after you edit your question, I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Salesforce stackexchange community.

Answer is "Yes". Here you need to create application event. For more information find this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_example.htm)

Comment: This is quite different to what you do in LWC, so rather depends on what technology the OP is using.

Comment: I will try to communicate between Parent with Grand Son component not able to do.but Between parent to child and vise Versa, it is working